# How can I get the name of an applied effect instance in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects

In After Effects, as a plug-in, I would like to get the name of an applied effect. For example, if my installed effect name is "FoofooBerry", and the customer applied two FoofooBerry effects, there would be one named "FoofooBerry" and one named "FoofooBerry 2".

In the documentation, it says:

> To get an effect’s instance name (as renamed by the user), get the
>   AEGP_StreamRef for the effect itself and call AEGP_GetStreamName.

That seems like what I want to do, but how one would "get the AEGP_StreamRef for the effect itself" eludes me.

I've tried iterating over all streams on the effect and inspecting them, but I don't see anything useful. Anyone know how to get the stream ref for an effect (not a stream on that effect)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted to the adobe forums and got an answer: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4057445#4057445. The piece I was missing was AEGP_NewParentStreamRef.